# How to draw several copies of the same actor on one stage at different positions?

Tags: libgdx

I want to draw several copies of an actor on the same stage.

Here what I've done :

// class Test

public class Test extends Image {

```
private Sprite sprite;
private Rectangle bounds;
private final float HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

public Test() {

    // Sprite
    Texture texture = new Texture("img.png");
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    sprite = new Sprite(texture);

    // adjusting sprite size to different resolutions
    float imgHeightRatio = 120.0f / 480.0f;
    float imgWidthHeightRatio = sprite.getWidth() / sprite.getHeight();


    float newHeight = imgHeightRatio * HEIGHT;
    float newWidth = imgWidthHeightRatio * newHeight;

    clockSprite.setSize(newWidth, newHeight);

    // setting the size of the actor
    setSize(sprite.getWidth(), sprite.getHeight());


    // sprite bounds
    bounds = new Rectangle();
}

public void setBounds(Rectangle bounds) {
    this.bounds = bounds;
}

@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
// drawing sprite
    batch.draw(sprite, bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());
}
```

} // end of test class

// class MyStage

public class MyStage extends Stage {

```
private Array<Test> actors;
private Rectangle rect1, rect2, rect3;

public MyStage(Test t) {
    // Rectangles
    rect1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, t.getWidth(), t.getHeight());
    rect2 = new Rectangle(30, 30, t.getWidth(), t.getHeight());
    rect3 = new Rectangle(60, 60, t.getWidth(), t.getHeight());

    actors = new Array<Test>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        actors.add(t);
    }

    for(Test test : actors) {
        addActor(test);
        test.setBounds(rect1);
        test.setBounds(rect2);
        test.setBounds(rect3);
    }

}


public void act(float dt) {
    super.act(dt);
}

@Override
public void draw() {
    super.draw();
}

public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
}
```

} // end of MyStage class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot just simply duplicate **Actor** instance or add it more than once to the **Stage**, although you can assign for example the same **Texture** to all of them (but I'm not sure if it is reasonable - maybe because of memory when having dozens of same actor it is).

You can test it in very simple way:

```
Stage stage;
Actor a = new Actor();

stage.addActor(a);

System.out.println(stage.getActors().size);

stage.addActor(a);

System.out.println(stage.getActors().size); //same as above
```

The best idea in my opinion is to create [ActorFactory](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) and for less complicated examples like your just **the method returning new instance of the Actor**

```
public Test getTestActor(float x, float y, float width, float height)
{
    //here you are creating Test instance, giving it bounds etc
}
```

Then you can just deal with it like

```
stage.addActor ( getTestActor(0, 0, t.getWidth, t.getHeight)
```

One thing more - if adding actor copies to the stage is the only reason you are extending it please don't. It will make your application far less flexible in future.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `setBounds` method should probably copy the values rather than the reference, so you don't risk passing the same Rectangle object to multiple different actors.

```
public void setBounds(Rectangle bounds) {
    this.bounds.set(bounds);
}
```

Add a method to your Test class that allows you to make a copy from a prototype:

```
public Test (Test test){
    this();
    setBounds(test.bounds);
}
```

Although in your case, you are assigning them different bounds anyway, so this is currently unnecessary. It is a mistake to be loading the texture from within the class constructor, because this will cause every instance of the class to load a duplicate copy of the texture when they could all be sharing a single copy. So really your constructors should be like this:

```
public Test(Texture texture) {

    sprite = new Sprite(texture);

    // adjusting sprite size to different resolutions
    float imgHeightRatio = 120.0f / 480.0f;
    float imgWidthHeightRatio = sprite.getWidth() / sprite.getHeight();

    float newHeight = imgHeightRatio * HEIGHT;
    float newWidth = imgWidthHeightRatio * newHeight;

    clockSprite.setSize(newWidth, newHeight);

    setSize(sprite.getWidth(), sprite.getHeight());

    // sprite bounds
    bounds = new Rectangle();
}

public Test (Test test){
    this();
    sprite.set(test.sprite);
    bounds.set(test.bounds);
}
```

Now it makes sense to make copies of this. So to set up your test case:

```
public MyStage(Test prototypeTest) {
    int width = prototypeTest.getWidth();
    int height = prototypeTest.getHeight();
    rect1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    rect2 = new Rectangle(30, 30, width, height);
    rect3 = new Rectangle(60, 60, width, height);

    actors = new Array<Test>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        actors.add(new Test(prototypeTest));
    }

    for(Test test : actors) {
        addActor(test);
        test.setBounds(rect1);
        test.setBounds(rect2);
        test.setBounds(rect3);
    }

}
```