# Table does not draw following rows

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I tried to draw multiple tables with one stage, so far it worked with two tables in different rows, but when I try to add the 3rd or 4th it doesn't work. I tried to draw the tables alone and they work but not in combination which is funny, because they work for 2 Tables....

I tried drawing the tables single alone and they worked but not in combination.

```
public void setupScreen() {
    TextureAtlas menuUi = assetManager.get(Assetdescriptor.backGround);
    TextureRegion backGroundRegion = menuUi.findRegion(Regionnames.backGround);

    Skin menuSkin = assetManager.get(Assetdescriptor.skinUI);


    TextButton team1 = new TextButton("Team 1", menuSkin, "Team1");

    TextButton team2 = new TextButton("Team 2", menuSkin, "Team1");

    TextButton team3 = new TextButton("Team 3", menuSkin, "Team3");

    TextButton team4 = new TextButton("Team 4", menuSkin, "Team4");

    TextButton team5 = new TextButton("Team 5", menuSkin, "Team5");


    TextButton player1 = new TextButton("Spieler 1", menuSkin);
    player1.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            System.out.println("Clicked");
        }
    });

    TextButton player2 = new TextButton("Spieler 2", menuSkin);

    TextButton kiPanzer1 = new TextButton("Ki Panzer 1", menuSkin);

    TextButton kiPanzer2 = new TextButton("Ki Panzer 2", menuSkin);

    TextButton kiPanzer3 = new TextButton("Ki Panzer 3", menuSkin);


    Table teamTable1 = new Table();
    Table teamTable2 = new Table();
    Table teamTable3 = new Table();
    Table teamTable4 = new Table();
    Table teamTable5 = new Table();



    Table TeamOverview = new Table();
    Table spieler1= new Table(); // Spieler 1
    Table spieler2= new Table(); // Spieler 2
    Table Ki3     = new Table(); // Ki Panzer
    Table Ki4     = new Table(); // Ki Panzer
    Table Ki5     = new Table(); // Ki panzer


    spieler1.add(player1);
    spieler2.add(player2);
    Ki3.add(kiPanzer1);
    Ki4.add(kiPanzer2);
    Ki5.add(kiPanzer3);


    TeamOverview.add(team1, team2, team3, team4, team5);

    teamTable1.center();
    teamTable1.add(spieler1,spieler2,Ki3,Ki4,Ki5);
    teamTable2.center();
    teamTable2.add(spieler1,spieler2,Ki3,Ki4,Ki5);
    teamTable3.center();
    teamTable3.add(spieler1,spieler2,Ki3,Ki4,Ki5);
    teamTable4.center();
    teamTable4.add(spieler1,spieler2,Ki3,Ki4,Ki5);



    Table table = new Table();
    table.add(TeamOverview);
    table.add(teamTable1).row();
   -- -These are the tables which dont work---
    table.add(teamTable2).row();
    table.add(teamTable3).row();
    table.add(teamTable4).row();
    -----------------------------------


    table.setFillParent(true);
    table.setBackground(new TextureRegionDrawable(backGroundRegion));
    table.pack();

    stage.addActor(table);

}
```

There is no error message, but there is no change in drawing expected result is 6 rows but there is only 2.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you are not allowed to reuse the same object's (spieler1,spieler2,Ki3,Ki4,Ki5). Create unique instance for every time you add them to the different tables.

Check com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group#addActor
(which Table extends from)

```
    public void addActor (Actor actor) {
        if (actor.parent != null) {
            if (actor.parent == this) return;
            actor.parent.removeActor(actor, false);
        }
        children.add(actor);
        actor.setParent(this);
        actor.setStage(getStage());
        childrenChanged();
    }
```

A actor can only have one parent, the previous one is removed.
Your table might still have all the rows you want, they are just empty.
You can use setDebug(true) to see the drawing 'lines'.

Edit
This question seems to be a duplicate anyway.
Refer to
 [How to draw several copies of the same actor on one stage at different positions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32372804/how-to-draw-several-copies-of-the-same-actor-on-one-stage-at-different-positions)